# Catalina and VM Ware SSH broken Pipe

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, macos-catalina

I upgraded to Catalina yesterday and now all of my SSH connections to VM Fusion (cent os) images get a broken pipe after about 5 seconds.   I've tried setting

```
Host 
*\ServerAliveInterval 120
```

within my ~/.ssh/config file but it didn't make a difference.

SSH connections to other machines seems to work fine.

Anybody have any ideas on what to try next?